# How to print complete http request using chalice?

Tags: python, rest, aws-lambda, chalice

I have a small application where I am using chalice to expose some endpoints. For logging purpose I want to print the entire url whenever any handler function is called.

```
@app.route('/XYZ', methods=['GET'])
@logging_and_error_handling()
def get_XYZ_value():
```

For example , if the above function gets called, I want to log the entire url using `app.log.info()`.
Something like `call to http://myhostname.com/api/XYZ started`

I tried using `app.current_request.to_dict()`, but it looks like it doesn't have that info. [Git reference](https://github.com/aws/chalice).

Is there an alternate way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `app.current_request.context['resourcePath']` for the URL and also log the following as well:

- `app.current_request.method`
- `app.current_request.uri_params`
- `app.current_request.query_params`
- `app.current_request.context.get('requestId')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `app.current_request.context['Path']`, not use `app.current_request.context['resourcePath']`

if
path of custom domain api mapping is: xxxxx
your custom domain is: a.com

when a client is using `a.com/xxxxx/XYZ` to access your lambda,
`app.current_request.context['resourcePath']` will be "/XYZ",
`and app.current_request.context['Path']` will be "/xxxxx/XYZ"